# Korganizer looks stranger on elementary OS

Tags: settings, applications, qt

[image]

The calendar folder in the lower left corner looks like this which makes me uncomfortable,but it appears right in kde. So do I need to install some dependences ? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Installing libqt5libqgtk2 solves this issue.